# the content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe

Tags: facebook

I have published my new webpage yesterday (webolucija . net), and the problem is that facebook does not allow to share(message, comment, post) my website url..

This is what show out when I try to send my url on chat:

> the content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe

Comment: Did you resolved it. Even I am getting same error in my app. it was working before but suddenly after 2 days i a m getting above error. if solved this please post you suggestions

Comment: Hi Roster, unfortunately, I didn't solve it. I bought new domain, but you can try this : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing much you can do. You are at the mercy of Facebook. But here is what you can do to give it a shot if at all Facebook considers your request.

- The owner or your followers who post your website links on Facebook
  can click the "let us know" link to make Facebook that it is a
  mistake.
- Another thing the owner can do is to go to
  "https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131" and post
  a review request.

Not to discourage you but let's be honest Facebook won't care to respond individually to those review requests.

One of our sites (https://www.wiki11.com) was also blocked by Facebook, and even after submitting a couple of review requests, there hasn't been a single response from Facebook. So we stopped using Facebook for that particular website and started using Twitter and Google+ more.

If any of you faced a similar situation and resolved it, kindly care to share your experience. I'd like to know your story.

Thanks.